# How to change the width of area around SelectInput in R shiny

Tags: r

I have a SelectInput in R and there is a lot of blank space around it.  Here is the select input in my ui.r:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(GetHeader()),

 sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("date", "Select Date:", GetListOfDays(), width="120px")
    #dateInput("date", "Date:", GetListOfDays() ) #value = "2012-02-29")
  ),

  mainPanel(
   uiOutput("plots")
  )
```

Now when I run the report I see:

[image]

Do you see all the blank space to the left of the select input?  How can I trim that or remove it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343611/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-sidebarpanel-without-affect-subsequent-sidebarpanel-w

Comment: Hi, see edit that did not work I think because I am using pageWithSidebar and he has a custom threepage thing.

Comment: By the way, do you mean all of the space to the right?  Just want to make sure I understand the question...

Comment: I'd like to remove all the space to the right of the right edge of the button

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like there is a `width` argument right in the function.

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(GetHeader()),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("date", "Select Date:", GetListOfDays(), width="120px"),
    width = 2 ### EDIT HERE
  ),

  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("plots")
  )
```